# Eigenfunctions of Momentum Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, eigenvalue, linear-systems

Suppose we have the 1-d wave function $\psi(x)=A\sin\left(\frac{p_0x}{\hbar}\right)$ and we want to know wheter this is an eigenfunction for $\hat{p}=-i\hbar\dfrac{d}{dx}$

The argument usually goes about splitting the sine into a sum of complex exponentials, and thus getting $\pm \hbar k$ as eigenvalues, and, since a superpositions of eigenvalues isn't necessary a eigenvalue, $\psi$ isn't a eigenfunction of $\hat{p}$.

My question is pretty simple, why do this? Can't we simply apply the operator on $\psi$ and note that you can't multiply a cosine by a constant to get a sine?

Comment: "The argument usually goes [...]"?? Where? Who does so? Of course it is much more straightforward to simply apply the operator to the given function.

Comment: McIntyre's QM book is an example. Either way, writing it as superposition of eigenstates helps to calculate expected values and such, so I guess that's what's up.

Answer (score 5):

Your method is valid too. Of course you can just calculate
$$\hat{p}\psi(x) 
  =-i\hbar\dfrac{d}{dx}A\sin\left(\frac{p_0x}{\hbar}\right)
  =-ip_0 A\cos\left(\frac{p_0x}{\hbar}\right)$$
and observe that this is not a multiple of
$\psi(x)=A\sin\left(\frac{p_0x}{\hbar}\right)$.
And hence $\psi(x)$ is not an eigenfunction of $\hat{p}$.

Answer (score 4):

A state that is a superposition of different eigenfunctions would be a superposition of different momentum states. A measurement would have probabilities of finding each value.